# When will Aysnc method or Class will execute?

Tags: apex, batch, future, asynchronous, queueable

We have a case object subject field. When the case is created, Trigger fires and update the subject, then flows fire to update subject again..Now i have a future method or Queueable class or batch class that will get called from Case Trigger Handler.

When will actually those async transaction will be executed?  Will Async transaction wait for the Sync transaction to be committed?

Reason of asking::: if I pass Sobject to queueable from trigger handler later the subject got modified again in the same sync transaction, the queueable will have old
value of subject or new value?